# Create a ms access report using a combobox

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have been looking at YouTube for a month learning MS Access.  I've created a MS Access report that displays all required info from three tables for 45 distinct systems in my inventory.  I want to create a combobox so that the report is only generated for a specific system instead of all 45 as it is doing now.  The data bases are joined by the data field called Acronym.  I can create a form with a combobox with the acronym's displaying and can select the acronym in the combobox.  I cannot figure out how to tie that specific acronym back to generate only the report for that acronym.  The report is called RptSystemProfile.

Answer (score 0):

The `DoCmd.OpenReport` has an optional `WhereCondition` parameter. you can do something like

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "RptSystemProfile", acViewPreview, _
    WhereCondition := "SystemID=" & cboSystem.Value
```

This assumes that the system is identified by a column called `SystemID` (adapt it to reflect the real name). This column must be selected in the query the report is based on. It also assumes this column is a `Long`

If the column is a string then write

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "RptSystemProfile", acViewPreview, _
    WhereCondition := "SystemID='" & cboSystem.Value & "'"
```

The also assumes that this Id is the `BoundColumn` column of the [Access ComboBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.combobox).

You can have a ComboBox display a text but be bound to an id. The row source of the ComboBox would be a query similar to

```
SELECT SystemId, SystemName FROM tblSystem ORDER BY SystemName
```

Then set `BoundColumn` to `1` and `ColumnWidths` to `0cm`. This hides the first column and displays only the text.

The `Value` property of the ComboBox then reflects the Id of the selected system.

Comment: Hi Olivier, thanks for the assistance.  The first time I tried it, some of the data displayed for a single system in the report.  After that, the report displays the Acronym in the report but no other info.  In the RptSystemProfile Record Source, I have 45 fields identified across 3 tables.  For some reason, I'm thinking I need a filter to display all the data in the 3 tables associated to the acronym.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Without seeing the query (SQL) it is difficult to give more details.